# Why are the functions making Vector an instance of Functor, Monad, Applicative, Alternative, Foldable and Traversable slow?

Tags: performance, haskell

The changelog for version 0.8 of [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.8) lists the following change with a warning:

> Functor, Monad, Applicative, Alternative, Foldable and Traversable
>   instances for boxed vectors *(WARNING: they tend to be slow and are
>   only provided for completeness)*.

Could someone explain why this is the case? Is it just the normal cost of typeclass specialization, or something more interesting?

**Update:** Looking at some particular instances, one sees for example:

```
instance Foldable.Foldable Vector where
  {-# INLINE foldr #-}
  foldr = foldr
```

and similarly for the other folds. Does this mean that folding is slow for `Vector`s in general? If not, what makes a non-specialized fold slow enough to warrant a warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I submitted the original set of these instances to Roman a year and a half ago and have maintained vector-instances since then. (I had to remove these instances from vector-instances once they migrated into vector, and now maintain it solely for the really exotic stuff). His concern was that if folks used these instances *polymorphically* then the RULES that make Vectors fuse away can't fire unless the polymorphic function gets inlined and monomorphized.

They exist because not every bit of code on the planet is Vector-specific and even then it is nice to sometimes use the common names.

Slow here is relative. The worst case is they perform like anybody else's folds, binds, etc. but Roman takes every single boxed value as a personal insult. :)

Answer (score 8):

I've just had a quick look at the source code and the implementations don't look excessively slow. I'd argue the authors added this warning because when you're writing a program in the `Vector` monad, you're working from such a high-level point of view that it's easy to forget that every `>>=` is, in fact, a `concatMap`, which tends to be inherently slow.

Another thing: `Vector` is particularly fast for unboxed types. So a user might be attracted to use the monad notation (for convenience), while he should actually be using an unboxed type (for speed).

Comment: That's an interesting take. I'll wait a little while before accepting the answer though, in case a less speculative one shows up. (Oh, and I don't mean to be negative when I say that... I guess the question is somewhat speculative in itself -- "what did the authors of vector *mean* when they wrote the warning?").

Comment: No problem, I would do the same in this case — my answer is just an educated guess.